# Spring data MongoDb Aggregation lookup from String to ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, lookup-tables

I'm using Spring (boot) data 2.2.7 with mongodb 4.0. 
I've set 3 collections that I'm trying to join via an aggregation lookup operation.

- catalog
- stock
- operations

**catalog**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec7856eb9eb171b72f721af"),
    "model" : "HX711",
    "type" : "DIGITAL",
....
}
```

mapped by

```
@Document(collection = "catalog")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String _id;
    @TextIndexed
    private String model;
....
```

**stock**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec78573b9eb171b72f721ba"),
    "serialNumber" : "7af646bb-a5a8-4b86-b56b-07c12a625265",
    "bareCode" : "72193.67751691974",
    "productId" : "5ec7856eb9eb171b72f721af",
......
}
```

mapped by

```
@Document(collection = "stock")
public class Component implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String _id;
    private String productId;
....
```

the *productId* field refers to the *_id* one in the catalog collection

**operations**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec78671b9eb171b72f721d3"),
    "componentId" : ""5ec78573b9eb171b72f721ba",
    .....

}
```

mapped by

```
public class Node implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String _id;
    private String componentId;
....
```

the *componentId* field refers to the *_id* one in the stock collection

I want to query **operations** or **stock** collection to retreive the corresponding Node or Component object list ordered by the Product.model field (in the **catalog** collection.)

While the goal is to code in Java I've tried to make the request first in the **Mongo shell** but I can't even get it working as I'm trying to join (lookup) a string with an ObjectId :  Node.componentId -> Component._id
Component.productId -> Product._id

For the relationship Component(stock) -> Product(Catalog) I've tryed

```
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
        .from("catalog")
        .localField("productId")
        .foreignField("_id")
        .as("product");

TypedAggregation<Component> agg =
        Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Component.class,
                lookupOperation
        );


AggregationResults<Component> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "stock", Component.class);
return results.getMappedResults();
```

but it returns the whole components records without product info.

```
[{"_id":"5ec78573b9eb171b72f721b0","uuId":"da8800d0-b0af-4886-80d1-c384596d2261","serialNumber":"706d93ef-abf5-4f08-9cbd-e7be0af1681c","bareCode":"90168.94737714577","productId":"5ec7856eb9eb171b72f721a9","created":"2020-05-22T07:55:31.66","updated":null}, .....]
```

thanks for your help.

---

**Note:**
In addition to @Valijon answer to be able to get the result as expected the returned object must include a "product" property either nothing is returned (using JSON REST service for example)

```
public class ComponentExpanded implements Serializable {

    private String product;
....
```

with

```
AggregationResults<ComponentExpanded> results =
        mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg,mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Component.class), ComponentExpanded.class);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem resides in the mismatch of types between `productId` and`_id` as you have observed.

To join such data, we need to perform [uncorrelated sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) and not every "new" feature makes it immediately into abstraction layers such as `spring-mongo`.

Try this:

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(l -> new Document("$lookup",
    new Document("from", mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Product.class))
        .append("let", new Document("productId", new Document("$toObjectId", "$productId")))
        .append("pipeline",
                Arrays.asList(new Document("$match",
                        new Document("$expr",
                                new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$_id", "$$productId"))))))
        .append("as", "product")),
    Aggregation.unwind("product", Boolean.TRUE));

AggregationResults<Component> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, 
    mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Component.class), Component.class);
return results.getMappedResults();
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lWEmvxWAlWD) Check here how shell query looks like.

**Note:** For Java `v1.7`, you need to implement `AggregationOperation` like below:

```
AggregationOperation l = new AggregationOperation() {

    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new Document(...); // put here $lookup stage
    }

};
```

Comment: Understood, you create a Bson Document based lookup operation with a pipeline using an internal field converted as ObjectId from the original one. Am I right suggesting that the unwind operation in not needed as in my model as it's a one-to-one relationship ?. I've updated the question (@see note) , am I right also to provide a different object to return result. Anyhow your solution works. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Emmanuel well, when you perform `$lookup`, it performs `left outer join` and create `array` field with `0...n` cardinality. In your case, probably it will be always array with 1 item, so thats why I've added extra `$unwind` operator to flatten array into single field. You can setup as output class any compatible class where MongoDB will attempt convert BSON Document into your class. You are welcome.

Comment: would you have an idea about coding the cascading lookup operations to flatten Node.componentUuId -> Component.productUuId -> Product.uuId. I mean getting a populated Node result document with its componet and product embedded ? I got it in the mongo shell then designed a a class according to the desired structure but I face an unpredictable null pointer exception .. without debug capability. notive : as I didn't had time to implement your solution to solve string -> objectId conversion I'm using my internal object uuids relationship. I will implement it latter. And thanks again ^^

Comment: @Emmanuel Please provide example. If I understand you correctly, inside uncorrelated sub-query, you can perform another `$lookup`, so on... Post how `Node` and `Component` are related, so I can check how do you need to build your query.

Comment: @Valijon this answer really helped

Comment: Feature request https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/3322