# Spring Boot MongoDB Lookup not working with ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I've `user` collection which has role object which has roleId. I also have `roles` collection which has id.
Now,for each role, I'd like to get the list of users.

Ex:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Scott",
        "role": {
            "roleId": "123432"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "role": {
            "roleId": "123432"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Scott",
        "role": {
            "roleId": "556432"
        }
    }
]
```

Roles Data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "123432"
        "name": "admin",
        "type": "internal"
    },
    {
        "id": "556432"
        "name": "owner",
        "type": "external"
    },
    {
        "id": "556432"
        "name": "owner",
        "type": "internal"
    } 
]
```

Now  I want to get all the roles of type `internal` and their related users:

So, the output should be,

```
[
    {
       "role": "123432",
        "users": [
            {
                "name": "Scott",
                "role": {
                    "roleId": "123432"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "John",
                "role": {
                    "roleId": "123432"
                }
            }
        ],
        { 
            "role": "556432",
            "users": []
         }
    }
]
```

This is my aggregation in SpringBoort:

```
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().from("roles").localField("roleId")
                .foreignField("_id").as("roles");

        AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("type").is("internal"));

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation, match);

        List<UserDTO> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "users", UserDTO.class).getMappedResults();
```

This is working great when roleId is in the form of ObjectId(Ex: ObjectId("556432")). But it's not working if it's in String(Ex: "556432").

Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: Seems like there is a similar issue discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61963518/spring-data-mongodb-aggregation-lookup-from-string-to-objectid

Comment: Both should be in the same type. So you may convert string to objectId or objectId to string